# Angular boot error npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: json, angular, npm

I have this problem when I want boot Angular project

tried install plugins

```
{
  "name": "portal-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

> You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the
>   serve command.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! portal-app@0.0.0
>   start: ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the portal-app@0.0.0 start
>   script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above. npm WARN Local package.json
>   exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-24T06_32_19_277Z-debug.log
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: *You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command*. What is unclear? Note that if you're really using AngularJS, then you shouldn't be using ng, which is a tool for Angular, not for AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is clear and meaningful : you need to be inside your project to run your command. You'll maybe need to use the change directory command to place your command prompt at the right location before launching your npm scripts.

So :

```
cd /path/to/projectDirectory
npm start
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I got this type of error when running ng test --karma-config=karma.conf.js --code-coverage, and the cause of problem were console.log statements in the code